How to save model state in pytorch fsdp
I am using PyTorch's FSDP. How can I save the completed model state every 100 batches?
Is the following code correct?
if (batch + 1) % 100 == 0:
    if isinstance(model, FSDP):
        states = model.state_dict()
        if is_main_process:
            ckpt = {'model_state_dict': states}
            torch.save(ckpt, 'ckpt.pth')
    else:
        if is_main_process:
          ckpt = {'model_state_dict': model.state_dict()}
          torch.save(ckpt, 'ckpt.pth')


or
if (batch + 1) % 100 == 0:
    if isinstance(model, FSDP):
          if is_main_process:
            with FSDP.summon_full_params(module=model):
                  ckpt = {'model_state_dict': model.state_dict()}
                  torch.save(ckpt, 'ckpt.pth')
    else:
        if is_main_process:
          ckpt = {'model_state_dict': model.state_dict()}
          torch.save(ckpt, 'ckpt.pth')

